# ActiveRecord .where of .join / has_one :through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have three models - `Patient`, `Location` and `Area`.

Every patient belongs to a location, and locations belong to areas.
Areas have a boolean value called `inpatient`.

I need to select the patients who belong to a location that in turn belongs to an area with the inpatient value set to true.

I have tried the following but none are working:

```
@inpatient = Area.joins(:locations).joins(:patients).where(inpatient: true).count
@inpatient = Patient.joins(:location).join(:area).where(area: {inpatient: true}) 
@inpatient = Patient.joins(:area).where(area: {inpatient: true}).all 
@inpatient = Patient.joins(:location).joins(:area).where(area: {inpatient: true}).count
```

Would appreciate some help! I imagine this is simple and that I'm getting something basic wrong... I've had a look at the other questions which are similar but have been unable to re-purpose the answers into anything that works.

---

**MODELS**

```
class Patient < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :location, optional: true
  has_one :area, through: :location

end
```

-

```
class Location < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :patients
  belongs_to :area, optional: false

end
```

-

```
class Area < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :locations
  has_many :patients, through: :locations

end
```

Comment: What does `none are working` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close. You have to use the table names in the where statement, NOT the relation name. Also, you have to use areas within the locations argument. Try this:

```
@inpatient = Patient.joins(:location).joins(:area).where(locations: {areas: {inpatient: true}})
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. Should have thought of nesting the `.where` argument... N.B. theres a typo in your answer - should be `.joins(:area)`

Comment: @Noah What if we use `joins(location: :area)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your associations, it should produce the same SQL query, but it is more simple and readable

```
@inpatient = Area.where(inpatient: true).patients
```